# "Other results" for pie chart data

Tags: mysql

For example, let's say I have a table with a list of people's names, and the ID of the country they come from. If I were to make a pie chart showing how many people come from each country, and I show all of them, that would amount to so many parts on the pie chart that the lines would be barely distinguishable.

So let's say the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS n, countryId
FROM persons
GROUP BY countryId
ORDER BY n DESC
```

If I limit the number of results in this query to top 20 by adding `LIMIT 20` to the end of it, that would make the entire pie chart much more readable, as it would display only 20 divisions. But the visual representation of it would be incorrect. The entire pie chart would no longer represent all people, it would represent the top 20 countries only.

So from there, if I want the entire circle of the pie chart to represent actually all of my people in the database, what I would like is that 21st part of the pie chart that would amount to, let's say 14%, and would contain all people that belong to any countries which are not in the top 20.

My question is, can this be done in a single query? And if so, how?

I know I could do another query here that would count the number of results from countries that aren't in the top 20, but I'm trying to avoid two queries for this solution, if possible.

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS n
FROM persons 
WHERE countryId NOT IN ( {$concatenatedIdsFromPreviousQuery} )
```

Comment: You can easily handle it in the code of your application.

Comment: You shouldn't bother. The total number of countries in the world is small enough that you could add the chart logic in your application. Just use your original query, set a threshold under which entries are grouped in the "Other" chart area, and that's that. No need to overcomplicate your queries for such simple application logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use your first query and decide in the application code how many countries to display by themselves and how many to display into an "others" group. For example, if the first three countries in the result set contain 95% of the user base, the chart will contain 17 countries whose pie slices will be indistinguishable because their percentages are below 1%.

You can either put a threshold on the number of countries to display standalone or on their percentages but either way, the actual values you get from the database can make the chart look bad in some cases.

#### Disclaimer

**This answer is provided as a proof of concept.** I do not recommend using it in production code for two reasons:

- it is slow because of the inner queries; it took 1.06 second to process a table of 3.76 million rows on an idle server; depending on your environment and application, this time may be acceptable or huge;
- it is not flexible enough; see the explanation above.

### The code

Let's build the query in two steps. First, let's write a query that produces the numbers displayed in the chart both in absolute values and as percentages:

```
SELECT countryId, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons) AS percent
FROM persons
GROUP BY countryId
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

This query counts the number of persons from each country and also computes the ratio of the value from the total number of persons in the table, expressed as percentage.

Some remarks:

- The inner query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons` counts the number of persons in the table. It is needed to compute the percentages. It can be extracted in a separate query and its value stored in a variable:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @total FROM persons;
  SELECT countryId, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
      COUNT(*)*100/@total AS percent
  FROM persons
  GROUP BY countryId
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
  ```

  but it doesn't improve the execution time. MySQL is smart enough to run the inner query only once and use the result for the outer query (it does the variable trick by itself, internally, because the inner query does not depend on the outer query, it always return the same value).
- Because it is multiplied by `100`, the value computed in `percent` is the final value to be displayed in the chart. For usual processing it is better to compute the ratio as `COUNT(*)/@total` and multiply the value with `100` only when it is displayed in the UI.

#### Step 2

We can now process the result set produced by the above query to aggregate the countries from the bottom of the list in a single group:

```
SELECT IF(percent < 5, -1, countryId) AS groupId,
    IF(percent < 5, 1, 0) AS isGroup,
    SUM(cnt) AS cnt, SUM(percent) AS percent
FROM (
    SELECT countryId, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons) AS percent
    FROM persons
    GROUP BY countryId
) t
GROUP BY groupId
ORDER BY isGroup ASC, percent DESC
```

#### Explanation

The query uses a threshold of `5%` to decide if the country is displayed standalone or it is added to the group of "other countries".

`groupId` is `-1` for the group of "other countries" or the `countryId` for countries that are displayed in the chart.

`isGroup` (`1` or `0`) is used to get the group at the end of the list, after the standalone countries (`ORDER BY isGroup ASC`). The list of standalone countries is then sorted by `percent DESC`. There is no need to have `isGroup` in the `SELECT` list, you can replace its definition directly into the `ORDER BY` clause.

#### Extra

If you have the list of countries in the source code then this is your query. But if you have the list in a table in the database then you probably need to get their names too. Joining the `countries` table, the query becomes:

```
SELECT IF(percent < 5, '-- other countries --', c.countryName) AS groupId,
    SUM(cnt) AS cnt, SUM(t.percent) AS percent
FROM (
    SELECT p.countryId, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons) AS percent
    FROM persons p
    GROUP BY countryId
) t
LEFT JOIN countries c ON t.countryId = c.countryId
GROUP BY groupId
ORDER BY IF(t.percent < 5, 1, 0) ASC, percent DESC
```

Joining the `countries` table does not significantly increase the execution time. There are about 200 countries in the world, the table `countries` is really small.

Comment: Someone's had a busy hour